# How to design auto-assign content coming from SQS?

Tags: redis, architecture, amazon-sqs, system-design

I have build the app that is responsible to moderate incoming content before letting it go to the main application. After someone has shared an alert, it falls into the sqs-in-queue. My app has a separate container that is responsible for executing background tasks, including checking queues for new messages.

Once a msg enters the system it is stored in dynamo db and the corresponding web socket message is sent to the frontend, notifying that a new alert has arrived.

User can log in to the system, assign an alert and moderate it.
Result will be saved to the db and moderated content will be sent to sqs-out.

I wanna implement auto-assign feature. As a moderator once I start my moderation clock, I should see one Alert that is assigned to me automatically. How to design that feature?

As I understand I need to track all active users in some db (which db to choose?) and be able to assign incoming content to the user which is free.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to have a queue of work that is "assignable" that gets enqueued after the item is stored in dynamo.  Just like your queue for incoming work, you need one of "assignable" work.  Clients can ask for work when they startup, the app will poll the queue, looking for assignable work.  When they finish their task, re-poll the queue to get the next available task.